# Local module dependencies with gradle

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-gradle-plugin, dependency-management, build.gradle

I have recently decided to switch my android project to the gradle build system from ant. Manually managing library and module dependencies between members of our team was quickly becoming too much work.

Everything began smooth. I have created a new gradle project, moved my sources and resources, and have gotten rid of all of the major third-party library .jars that we're hanging around my `/libs` folder so I could utilize the new gradle maven central dependencies. No problems there.

Now I am trying to find a good way to set up dependencies on some less popular modules that are not on maven central. I use a few small android modules (e.g a form validator, helper util module, etc) which I have become dependent on. The problem is that these modules are not simply .jars, but have resources as well. As far as I can tell, I can't just put these modules in my `/libs` folder and have gradle set up dependencies to them. I have read up on .aar files a bit and am looking for some advice on whether they are the answers to my problems or I am overlooking something simple. Below is my current directory structure (with some comments) and my `gradle.build`.

### directory structure

```
/<project-directory>
    /build
    /gradle
    /<application-directory>
        /build
        /src
        /libs <-- where I would expect to put non-maven modules
            /Form-Validator <-- MyApplication depends on this module
                /build.gradle
                /src
                    /java
                    /res
                    ... etc etc etc
            /Other-Module
        /build.gradle (seen below)
```

### build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.14.2'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.#####.############"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'

    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.8.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.2.0'

    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.4.0'
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem. What solution did you end up using?

Comment: I'm not sure- I no longer have access to the repo where this code lives. If you have your project in a public repo and can share it with me I can take a look and try to help.

Answer (score 1):

You can add your local maven repository to your build.gradle:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}
```

The location of the local repository depends on the OS. In Linux it's
$HOME/.m2/repository

Comment: My main concern is having all modules and dependencies under git version control so the entire project can be cloned from github and simply built without setting up individual local maven repos on every developers machine. Will this be possible?

Comment: I think it's possible yes. You could try to set the maven home dir of the project to the directory inside your git directory structure. like project/maven/repository

Comment: Thank you. I will give that a shot and report back!

Answer (score 0):

You can use JitPack currently.